# the type or namespace 'speaker' is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i am trying to create a speaker class in mvc(asp.net).. a message is displayed..

"The type or namespace Speaker is missing "

how to resolve this???

this is my controller file...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace white.Models
{
    public class session
    {
        public Int32 session_id { get; set; }

        public String title { get; set; }

        public String description { get; set;}

        public Int32 SpeakerId { get; set; }

        public Speaker speaker { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: is there is any class named Speaker ????

Comment: Error seems quite clear. Where is `Speaker` class defined?

Comment: Add a reference to the namespace that contains the class `Speaker`

Comment: Have you created the `Speaker` class? Where do you get the error? BTW, that is NOT your controller, that's your model

Comment: Side note: "`public class session`" - The ***overwhelming*** convention in C# and .Net is to make class names initially-capped (e.g., `Session` not `session`). You can do whatever you like, of course, but if anyone else is going to have to read/work with the code...

Comment: Expanding on T.J.'s comment...there is already a `Session` object in `ASP.NET` that is well known to any developers. You should give a more meaningful name to your model that doesn't create any confusion or possible name collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that `Speaker` isn't in `white.Models` and isn't in any of the system namespaces you're referencing. You'll need to add a `using` statement referencing its namespace (or use its fully-qualified name). If you're not sure what namespace it's in, either look at its documentation (if it's not your class) or look at the `Speaker.cs` file (if it is).

Comment: @Leo: What exception? The quoted error is a compile-time error.

Comment: well, I don't know...it's a complete mistery to me...there's no indication whether this is a runtime exception or compilation error, and from the question it's not exactly clear where the exception/error is happening

Comment: @Leo: I just happen to be all too familiar with that particular error message. :-) Yeah, the question is really vague.